# Are these Eclipse variables encrypted?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was doing some development on Java using Eclipse. After setting the break point, but found the variables are looks like in the following image, such as `a`, `a`, what does these mean, are they encrypted?

[image: Image 1]

I have done some other project, but the variables should have some readable names on them.

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Is that from your code? Did you use some obfuscator?

Comment: It is from some Development kit. I just run the examples, nothing with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are debugging code that has been obfuscated.  Specifically, the `AssemblerInput` class.  Either you obfuscated it yourself, or you are using a 3rd-party library that has been obfuscated.

Eclipse didn't do it ...

---

> It is from some Development kit. I just run the examples, nothing with the code.

Well, the library in the development kit is obfuscated.

> Any idea on how to restore that?

There is no way to restore the original symbols.  The only way forward is to request a non-obfuscated version of the library from the supplier ... or find an alternative to the library.

Comment: En, seems like this is the 3rd-party library that has been obfuscated.  Any idea on how to restore that? many thanks!

Comment: Actually there is a way, but it is hard. First, decompile all code to java and if this was done successfully (not all .class files may give java code because there are features not supported by java, and even classes produced by Scala may crash decompiler), try to understand everything in the code and assign more correct names to identifiers with the help of refactorings in your IDE.